# Pass selected value of md-select to function

Tags: angular, angular-material

```
       <md-select  i18n-placeholder="language|languages list @@lang" (change)="setLanguage(this.value)" 
           placeholder="Lang">
            <md-option value="Lt-uz">
                O'z
            </md-option>
            <md-option value="ru">Ru</md-option>
        </md-select>
```

The above code is passing undefined value. How to pass the selected value to the function ?

Comment: Bind the md-select to a backing `@Input` variable in your component TS.  On change, execute a function in your Component TS that uses the @Input variable.  You shouldn't need to explicitly pass the value from the md-select to a function.

Comment: Can you show us the `setLanguage()` function, please?

Comment: I used the way suggested by the author of the previous comment and it is working. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

1- You should never use this inside your template.

2- Your md-select is not bound to a class variable.

Try this :

```
<md-select  i18n-placeholder="language|languages list @@lang" 
           [(ngModel)]="selectedLanguage" 
           (change)="setLanguage()" 
           placeholder="Lang">
    <md-option value="Lt-uz">
         O'z
    </md-option>
    <md-option value="ru">Ru</md-option>
</md-select>
```

In your ts code :

```
export class YourTsClass{
   selectedLanguage:string = '';
   //....
   setLanguage(){
     //When this function will be called, selectedLanguage will have the selected value from md-select
    //You can then use this.selectedLanguage to access its value

   }            
}
```